# Laravel routing with a parameter using URL

Tags: url, laravel-5, routes

I am using datatables and I have a line with an entry number for a quotation.

The entry comes from

```
 $item->entry
```

What I am trying to do is wrap this in a href

```
<a href="{{URL('ProdecQuote/{$item->entry}')}}">{{ $item->entry }}</a>
```

my problem here is the $item within the route area does not translate to a number, instead I get

```
http://localhost:8000/ProdecQuote/{$item->entry}
```

Help would be gratefully appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
<a href="{{URL('ProdecQuote/', [$item->entry])}}">{{ $item->entry }}</a>
```

Hope it help you :)